# Styling Listview in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, listview

I have got a listview which is styled with css but dosent work.Am I missing something here.

```
<asp:ListView ID="msg_list" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <tr class="myitem">
        <td> <asp:Label role="menuitem" ID="msg_lbl" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("msg")%>' /> </td>
     </tr>
     <%--<hr style=" margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px; " />--%>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Here is the css

```
.myitem  
    {  
       background-color:Red;    
    }
```

Comment: your code should work. May be your style got overwritten with default style. Did you try with `!important`?

Comment: No I hadn't but i just did and still its not working.Actually its inside a dropdown of bootstrap..does that affect.

Comment: Is `.myitem` css class is available in this page?

Comment: any online demo available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table rows (tr) can't be styled as other elements (e.g. table cells (td)), meaning they don't react on every kind of styling. Why don't you just write:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRL29/5/)**

```
<asp:ListView ID="msg_list" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr class="myitem">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label role="menuitem" ID="msg_lbl" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("msg")%>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%--<hr style=" margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px; " />--%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>



tr.myitem td{
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    border:2px solid;
    background:red;
}
```

**OR**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRL29/6/)**

```
<asp:ListView ID="msg_list" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr class="myitem">
            <td>
                <asp:Label role="menuitem" ID="msg_lbl" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("msg")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%--<hr style=" margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px; " />--%></ItemTemplate>
```

```
.myitem {
    background:red;
}
```

**EDIT**

You need to add **`<table>`** tag

Comment: Won't that create a table in every row if the ListView?

Comment: Richa the background is working but margin isn't  `margin-left:30px !important;`

Comment: @user35 margin specifications are ignored for table cells Refer: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Comment: Check this for more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397142/cannot-put-margin-on-td-tag-with-neither-css-nor-cellspacing-attribute