# How to set spacing in html export of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993135/3014199) and get more spacing between columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,10],
                   'B': ['B','BBBBBB'],
                   'C': [0,1000],
                   'D': ['D','DDDDDD']})

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667535/3014199
spacing = dict(selector="table",props=[('border-collapse', 'separate'), 
                                       ('border-spacing',  '100px 500px')])

# Style
result=df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns[[0,2]], **{'text-align':'right'})\
               .set_properties(subset=df.columns[[1,3]], **{'text-align':'left'})\
               .set_table_styles([spacing])

print(result.render(),file=open('test.html','w'))
```

But despite ridiculous values, the columns don't seem any further apart.

adding e.g. `'padding-right':'10px',` in `set_properties` seems to work, but I want to do things right.

(Also, how can I suppress the index, it was `index=False` for `.to_html` but where to put it here?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to skip `selector="table"` to assign properties to `<table></table>`.

With `selector="table"` it assign for table inside table `<table><table></table></table>`.

---

You can use

```
result.render(head=[])`
```

to skip headers but there is still `<thread>` which moves other elements when  you use `'border-spacing'`

Using

```
dict(selector="thead", props = [('display', 'none')])
```

you can hide `<thread>`

You can also use skip `head=[]` and it will keep headers in file but you will no see them.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser


df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [1, 10],
        'B': ['B', 'BBBBBB'],
        'C': [0, 1000],
        'D': ['D', 'DDDDDD'],
     })

styles = [
    dict(
        props=[
            ('border-collapse', 'separate'), 
            ('border-spacing',  '10px 50px')
        ]
    ),
    dict(
        selector="thead",
        props = [('display', 'none')]
    )
]         

result = df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns[[0,2]], **{'text-align':'right'})\
               .set_properties(subset=df.columns[[1,3]], **{'text-align':'left'})\
               .set_table_styles(styles)

with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result.render(head=[]))

webbrowser.open('test.html')
```

---

BTW: I checked in source code: `render()` uses template [html.tpl](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/formats/templates/html.tpl). `to_html()` uses much complex methods to render HTML (ie. it uses class [HTMLFormatter](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1068)).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use bootstrap for the spaces

```
# Creates the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)

# Parses the dataframe into an HTML element with 3 Bootstrap classes assigned.
tables=[df.to_html(classes='table table-hover', header="true")]
```

in this example, I use the class "[table table-hover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-hover)" from Bootstrap